# Tastypie foreign key validation on POST

Tags: django, validation, tastypie

I'm having a really hard time figuring out where the best place to do complex error validation in tastypie is.

I have a `ModelResource`

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    object = fields.ToOneField(MasterPieceResource, "object")
    parent = fields.ToOneField("self", "parent", null=True)
```

I want to ensure that if the `POST` data contains a parent then the parent points to the same object. Note that the object and parent are provided in the `POST` data as uris

```
POST {
    parent: "/api/v1/comment/1/",
    object: "/api/v1/masterpiece/5/"
}
```

Where is the best place to do this error checking?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the validation section in the Tastypie [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/validation.html). You can use `FormValidation` or a custom `Validation` class.

Comment: Django Forms don't accept resource uris as parameters though. And even if we find a clean way to map uris to ids, checking it in the django forms means we need to load the foreign key objects from the database twice. First in the form, and again when we do the full_hydrate in obj_create. Is that really the cleanest way to do it?